# wordpress contact 7 URL Redirect with target=_blank

Tags: wordpress, redirect, plugins, contact-form-7

i wan to redirect my form after submit it i found the code which will do that
on_sent_ok: "location.replace('http://www.YOURSITE.com');"
but here is the twist i want redirect url with target blank .it means when visitor submit a form it will open a new page with target="_blank" link in contact 7 form of wordpress
please help me in it

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use client-side code, like javascript.

hope this code helps

```
<?php
if(condition==true) {
?>
    <script>
       window.open("http://www.example.com");
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: this is often blocked by browser

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments. but just to clear this: if You use Contact Form 7 plugin you just need to paste the following in Additional settings tab of your form:

```
on_sent_ok: "window.open('http://example.com/');"
```

http://example.com/ is your URL off course.

> But note, that you may have problems with browser popup settings,
>   because new tab is opening without user action/permission.